# Easiest way to achieve a simple one-to-many with a generic type using EF 4.1 code-first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, one-to-many

What is the best way to create a one to many relationship between two objects where one is a generic type? Is it even possible? What I mean is the following:

I have a Project object and the project can have multiple invoice dates

```
public class Project
{
    //...
    public List<DateTime> InvoiceDates;
    //...
}
```

I would like it to end up with one to many relationship in the Database. Do I have to wrap the DateTime object into my own object and define the navigation properties to have it created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to wrap the DateTime object into my own object and define
>   the navigation properties to have it created?

Yes. Entities must be reference types ( = `class` ) and `DateTime` is a `struct`. `List<DateTime>` is also not a primitive type which could be mapped to a column type in the database. So, you can only create an entity for this with its own table and a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Ok, and if I assume that I want numbers instead of dates (can be also kept as objects)? Is there any way to do that without creating an entity?

Comment: @MichalB.: No. A "trick" I can think of is to create a `string` property and column and append the numbers with a separator, like "1;5;9;18", etc. Your list property would not be mapped (only the string) and you create the list in the getter by parsing the string and in the setter you fill the string with separator from the number list.